# this code is giving me this error : Error: Could not find or load main class undefined

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project on android studio and i am editing an app and this code is giving me this error. this is a signin for an app

```
public void signin() {

    showpDialog();

    CustomRequest jsonReq = new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST, METHOD_ACCOUNT_LOGIN, null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    if (App.getInstance().authorize(response)) {

                        if (App.getInstance().getState() == ACCOUNT_STATE_ENABLED) {

                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(i);

                            ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(LoginActivity.this);

                        } else {

                            App.getInstance().logout();
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, getText(R.string.msg_account_blocked), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    } else {

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.error_signin), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    hidepDialog();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getText(R.string.error_data_loading), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            hidepDialog();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("username", username);
            params.put("password", password);
            params.put("clientId", CLIENT_ID);

            return params;
        }
    };

    App.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
}
```

Comment: Strange that the IDE is giving that error. Post the full logcat message. Are you running it from the terminal or the run button in Android Studio? Did you check what is running, your app or some java file? Did you rename/ delete/ move any java file from outside the IDE?

Comment: please check i posted the full code bellow

Comment: Please [edit] your question, don't post it as an answer unless it actually is